# Recognize error source (client or server) in Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-httpclient, ngrx-effects

I have [ngrx effect](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects) to login handling:

```js
 @Effect()
 authLogin = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(LOGIN_START),
   switchMap(() => this.http.post('/user/login')
     .pipe(
       catchError(
         (response) => {
           console.log('response instanceof HttpErrorResponse:', response instanceof HttpErrorResponse)
           return of(/* (...) */)
         }
       ),
     )
   ),
 )
```

and I need to recognize source of error in `console.log` place. I hoped that checking instance of `response` will be solution but not. `response` is always object type of `HttpErrorResponse`. If server answers HTTP Error (eg. 422) or if status is ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED (client error) is always `HttpErrorResponse`.

Comment: if you mean http error, you can check the status code, providing that your server is sending over the correct status code.

Answer (score 1):

for internet connection you can try **Navigator Object** that has many information about the browser

```
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
 if (!navigator.onLine) {
      console.error('not connected to internet', 'Network');
 } else if (401 === error.status) {

 } else if (400 === error.status) {

 }
 ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What error you can't handle, you should put them in the else block to show in console or what you want. Example:

```
catchError((response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (response.status === 401) {
            //do something
        } else if (response.status === 404) {
            //do something
        } else if (response.status === 403) {
            //do something
        } else if (response.status === 500) {
            //do something            
        } else {
            console.log(response.message, response.statusText);
        }
        return throwError(response);
    }
)
```

Now you can get other errors like internet problem can be discovered by else block